# redirect https traffic on Amazon via ELB and linux to static site on S3

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3

As known Amazon does not support https connection with custom URL to static site located on S3

To solve the problem I configured :

- Route53 with custom domain
- Load Balancer (ELB) to redirect port 443 to 80 + to install SSL license on it
- Amazon Linux server + ngnix on it for http redirection to domain name that Amazon provided for S3

on  Amazon Linux I configured in /etc/nginx/conf.d/virtual.conf :

```
      server {
             listen 80;
             server_name my_root_domain.com;
             rewrite     ^ $scheme://my_root_domain.com.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/$request_uri?      permanent;
         }
```

URL I get on web browser is "my_root_domain.com.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" instead of my_root_domain.com

Second question: I also want to redirect www.my_root_domain.com to S3

Thanks for any help , I just started with nginx

Comment: On #1 you don't want to url rewrite, you want to proxy, don't you?

Comment: user602525 I didn't think about it could be proxy thanks for comment, but how i can keep my _root_domain.com in browser url ?

Comment: I think that's what proxying will do. To the client it looks like it is hitting www.yourdomain.com the server goes to wherever you tell it and returns the content back to the client, but as far as the client is concerned it thinks it was at www.yourdomain.com the whole time. Look up forward proxy

Comment: Cloudfront supports this custom SSL now. You can put cloudfront infront of S3 bucket as orgin an it will work. Very expensive though $600/mo for a certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use nginx as a forward proxy, probably something like:

```
server {
             listen 80;
             server_name my_root_domain.com;
             location / {
                 proxy_pass http://my_root_domain.com.us-east-1.amazonaws.com;
             }
         }
```

Comment: .thanks for answer , I'll check and update . Interesting , Can I duplicate server_name line with/and without www in one server{} config ?

Comment: Just a follow up from earlier... but if you already have nginx set up, why aren't you just serving from nginx?